# How to disable the ability to select an item at Telerik's RadConversationView

Tags: telerik, windows-phone

I'm using RadConversationView to display chat.
There is default ability to select an item and it corrupts the labels with accept color which I'm trying t avoid.

XAML:

```
 <tlr:RadConversationView Name="ConversationView"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
                                     SendingMessage="ConversationView_OnSendingMessage"
                                     MessageTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}"
                                     >
            </tlr:RadConversationView>
```

And message template (incoming and outgoing are slightly different)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IncomingMessageTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="12">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <primitives:RadPointerContentControl Background="{StaticResource BrownBrush}"
                                             TargetPoint="-150,-300">
            <primitives:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Polygon Width="12"
                             Height="24"
                             Points="0,0 12,0 12,12 0,24"
                             StrokeThickness="0"
                             Fill="{StaticResource BrownBrush}"
                             RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                        <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                        </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                    </Polygon>
                </DataTemplate>
            </primitives:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>

            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Margin="12"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                   Margin="12, 0, 12, 12"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </primitives:RadPointerContentControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

How to disable this behavior?

Comment: Can you show a bit of your XAML? I've played a bit with the RadConversationView and I've found no properties related to selecting a message, nor any visual difference when trying to tap on a message

Comment: just update my post with a xaml sample. Message template was taken from telerik documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to your case is too override the TextBlock style in your datatemplate, to restore foreground to its default value:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IncomingMessageTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="12">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <primitives:RadPointerContentControl Background="{StaticResource BrownBrush}"
                                             TargetPoint="-150,-300">
            <primitives:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Polygon Width="12"
                             Height="24"
                             Points="0,0 12,0 12,12 0,24"
                             StrokeThickness="0"
                             Fill="{StaticResource BrownBrush}"
                             RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                        <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                        </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                    </Polygon>
                </DataTemplate>
            </primitives:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>

            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Margin="12"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                   Margin="12, 0, 12, 12"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </primitives:RadPointerContentControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```